# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on o83.pyWriteDynamicFrame

Tags: aws-glue

I try to write a single column to Aurora (Postgres)
The error is something I do not understand in the context of my code.

The `dfbetter.show()` prints a nice list of policiID's right before the error:

```
{"policyID": "223488"}
{"policyID": "433512"}
{"policyID": "142071"}
{"policyID": "253816"}
{"policyID": "894922"}
{"policyID": "422834"}
{"policyID": "582721"}
{"policyID": "842700"}
{"policyID": "874333"}
```

This is the script I use, I read from S3, that works fine. Then I turn the CSV file into a DynamicFrame with a single column and that also works fine.

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext


def main():
    glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

    dfnew = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", {'paths': ["s3://mybucket/data/"]}, format="csv", format_options={'withHeader':True})

    dfbetter = dfnew.select_fields('policyID')
    dfbetter.show()
    print(type(dfbetter))

    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=dfbetter, connection_type="postgresql", connection_options={
        "url": "theniceurl",
        "dbtable": "postgres.thijs_test",
        "user": "thijs",
        "password": "mypassword"
    })


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glue/scripts/gluecode/hello_world.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/glue/scripts/gluecode/hello_world.py", line 24, in main
    "password": "mypassword"
  File "/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/python/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 640, in from_options
  File "/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/python/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 241, in write_dynamic_frame_from_options
  File "/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/python/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/context.py", line 264, in write_from_options
  File "/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/python/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 35, in write
  File "/usr/share/aws/glue/etl/python/PyGlue.zip/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 31, in writeFrame
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:840)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper$.apply(JDBCUtils.scala:836)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.PostgresDataSink.jdbcWrapper$lzycompute(PostgresDataSink.scala:25)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.PostgresDataSink.jdbcWrapper(PostgresDataSink.scala:25)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.PostgresDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(PostgresDataSink.scala:37)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you confirm the number of partitions present in your dataframe just before writing to DB and also repartition to increase the number of partitions which will avoid this kind of issues

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's a single partition and when I do a `.repartition(100)` on the dataframe I end up with a hundred partitions but the same error nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got the `connection_options` wrong.
This is the right way.

```
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(frame=dfpartitioned,
                                                 connection_type="postgresql",
                                                 connection_options={
        "url": "jdbc:postgresql://superlonghostname:5432/public",
        "dbtable": "thijs_test",
        "user": "myuser",
        "password": "mypassword"
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit same error with sql server. After check super carefully, i found this refer to connection option has something wrong when hi this error. Check ur connection string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).